# Accordion height not set correctly for first time

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a jquery tab component. Into each tab i have an accordion. my problem is for the accordion within second tab. First time I switch from first tab to second tab, accordion's panel is not being adjusted to its content and appears a vertical scrollbar. However, if then I switch from second tab to first tab, and then again from first tab to second tab, it is working ok, and the successives times I do it as well. It is only failing the first time. What's wrong, below my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({
        activate: function (event, ui) {
            $("#accordion2").accordion({

                beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#accordion2").accordion({ clearStyle: true, autoHeight: false });
                    $(ui.newPanel).css('height', '100');
                    $(ui.newPanel).css('min-height', '100');
                    $(ui.newPanel).css('max-height', '400');
                    //$(ui.newPanel).css('overflow', 'visible');
                }
            }); // End Accordion
        } // End Activate tab
    }); // End tabs

    tabs.find(".ui-tabs-nav").sortable({
        axis: "x",
        stop: function () {
            tabs.tabs("refresh");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Try removing this line: `$(ui.newPanel).css('height', '100');` and see  if that solves something.

Comment: if i remove that line vertical scrollbar is showing as well, and then if I expand it, vertical scrollbar is kept as well. By keeping this line, vertical scrollbar is only shown for first time when i switch from 1st tab to 2nd tab, if I expand it and collapse again and so on, no vertical scrollbar is shown anymore.

Comment: Well, it happens because you are setting the height to maximum of 400. If the content is actually longer than those 400px vertical scrollbars will appear. Try removing all `min/max-height` properties and instead set `autoHeight` to true.

Comment: It behaves the same, vertical scrollbar appears. Also, my content is not longer than the 100px height. I think it is a bug with jquery accordion when put it inside jquery tabs, I have goolged a lot and I found many people with similar issues. The problem is that when in first tab, the other tabs are inactive so their height is set to 0px, then when you switch to them, their height continue being set to 0px.

Comment: this is because i set the heigth with that line in order to force to be set different from 0 but it seems to ignore the height I set the first time i move from 1st tab to 2nd tab. The rest of time it works.